# Getting an additional extra stroke on using linear gradient in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, linear-gradients

I am using linear gradient in iOS but there appears an additional stroke on the top and bottom. How to either remove or fill it.

[Fuzzy Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b34to.png)

I have used the below code for gradient.

```
            ctx.SaveState();

            var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB();
            CGGradient gradient = new CGGradient(colorSpace, colors, offsets);
            ctx.Clip();
            ctx.DrawLinearGradient(gradient, new CGPoint(rangeRect.Left, rangeRect.Top), new CGPoint(rangeRect.Right, rangeRect.Bottom), CGGradientDrawingOptions.None);
            ctx.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.Fill);

            colorSpace.Dispose();
            gradient.Dispose();
            ctx.RestoreState();
```

I have even tried with CGPathDrawingMode as FillStroke. But of no use.

Comment: Can you provide more codes about `colors` and `offsets`?

Comment: Offset values : 0, 0.5, 0.9,1.  I am using 4 colors with below color codes. #30B32D, #ed9a0b, #F03E3E, #D4150B

Comment: how did your use this `gradient` view? I test your code and it works well for me.